# Eclipse Plugin to retrieve active file length in package explorer

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I wrote this code to do the task, but the dialogue box doesn't appear. As soon as I use IFile or IResource in the code, dialogue box doesn't appear.

```java
package com.example.helloworld.handlers;
public class SampleHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
       IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event); 
       IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
       IWorkbenchWindow activeWorkbenchWindow = wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
       ISelectionService selectionService = activeWorkbenchWindow.getSelectionService();
       ISelection selection = selectionService.getSelection();
       IStructuredSelection structSelection = (IStructuredSelection) selection;
       IFile ir = ((IFile)((ICompilationUnit)structSelection.getFirstElement()).getResource());
       test = (String) ir.getName();
       MessageDialog.openInformation( window.getShell(),"File Size",String.format("\n\nSize = %s",test));
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: These are imports:

Comment: import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredSelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ITreeSelection;

Comment: import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreePath;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeSelection;
import org.eclipse.ui.ISelectionService;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbench;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;
import org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil;
import org.eclipse.jdt.*;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IAdaptable;

Comment: import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IAdapterFactory;

Comment: @greg-449 greg-449

Comment: So what have you done to debug this? What is the current selection? Is it actually an `ICompilationUnit`? Are you getting any error messages? Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directoy to see if there is anything there. Use the Eclipse debugger to step through your code.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I am new in eclipse and java. I have added an item ("File Size") in the context menu in package explorer. I right click on a java file in package explorer and select "File Size", so the selection is a Java file

Comment: I used Debug, i got this error : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit cannot be found by com.example.helloworld_1.0.0.qualifier

Comment: The problem is that as soon as i use any of IFile , IResource, .. dialogue box doesn't appear which means that program stops somewhere before that line of code

Comment: I seems that there is a problem with the ICompilationUnit Jar file, Am I right?

Comment: @greg-449 I appreciate if you can help me find the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public Object execute(final ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

    IStructuredSelection selection = HandlerUtil.getCurrentStructuredSelection(event);
    String test;
    Long size;
 if (!selection.isEmpty()) {
      IFile file = ((IFile)((ICompilationUnit)selection.getFirstElement()).getResource());
     if (file != null) {
       File realfile = file.getRawLocation().makeAbsolute().toFile();
       size = realfile.length();
       MessageDialog.openInformation(HandlerUtil.getActiveShell(event), "File Name",String.format(" %s", size));
      }
 } 
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern versions of Eclipse have many more helper methods so you can get the file in a much simpler way:

```java
@Override
public Object execute(final ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException
{
  IStructuredSelection selection = HandlerUtil.getCurrentStructuredSelection(event);

  if (!selection.isEmpty()) {
    IFile file = Adapters.adapt(selection.getFirstElement(), IFile.class);

    if (file != null {
      String name = file.getName();

      MessageDialog.openInformation(HandlerUtil.getActiveShell(event), "File Name",
                                    String.format("Name %s", name));
    }
  }
```

This is using `HandlerUtil.getCurrentStructuredSelection` to deal with getting the current structured selection from any view or editor.

It then uses `Adapters.adapt` which will convert ('adapt') the selection to an `IFile` if possible. This does not require `ICompilationUnit` and will work for any view or editor which uses files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply greg, Now i receive the smae error but this time for IFile: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile cannot be found by com.example.helloworld_1.0.0.qualifier

Comment: Dear greg I fixed that issue but not working yet, Just a question, What is "name"? Is it: String test = (String) file.getName();, maybe I made a mistake here, Shouldn't I get file.contents() first?

Comment: as I checked, "file" is null

Comment: IStructuredSelection selection = HandlerUtil.getCurrentStructuredSelection(event);
String test = "me";
 if (!selection.isEmpty()) {
 IFile file = Adapters.adapt(selection.getFirstElement(), IFile.class);
         if (file != null) {
           test = (String) file.getName();
         MessageDialog.openInformation(HandlerUtil.getActiveShell(event), "File Name",String.format("Name %s", test));
          }else {
  MessageDialog.openInformation(HandlerUtil.getActiveShell(event), "File Name",String.format("Name %s", "file is null"));

Comment: Sorry I missed out the line for 'name' - added. This code works for me, what exactly do you have selected when you test it? Not everything can  converted to a file. Use the 'edit' link just under your question to add to the question rather than putting code in comments.

Comment: For me there is no error but it doesn't work, IFile is null. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: I recieved this :org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile cannot be found by com.example.helloworld_1.0.0.qualifier

Comment: It sounds like you do not have the dependencies configured properly for your plugin. You must list plugin dependencies in the MANIFEST.MF `Require-Bundle` or `Import-Package` statements.